# Electric Potential Energy in $0$ space like dimensions and $t$ time like dimensions in the case of massive photons

Tags: electromagnetism, photons, spacetime, charge, geometry

Several months ago I asked about electric force in higher dimensions in the case of massive photons [What would be the force law for the electric force between two electric charges in higher dimensions in the case of photons that have rest mass?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/386225/what-would-be-the-force-law-for-the-electric-force-between-two-electric-charges?noredirect=1#comment870767_386225) and was told that, using natural units the equation for electric potential energy in higher dimensions in the case of massive photons would be $$\varphi(r) = \frac{ (m r)^{\frac{d}{2}-1} K_{\frac{d}{2}-1} (mr)}{(2 \pi)^\frac{d}{2}}\frac{1}{ r^{d-2}}$$

$K_n\left(x\right)$ is modified the bessel function of the second kind, and $d$ would be the number of spatial dimensions.

The geometry between multiple time like dimensions would be euclidean in flat time, just as the geometry between multiple space like dimensions is euclidean in flat space.  The geometry between a time like and space like dimension is not euclidean unless either time is treated as imaginary space or space is treated as imaginary time.  In the case of real numbers for both space like and time like dimensions in the pythagorean theorem, for the geometry between a space like and a time like dimension, one of the plus signs is replaced by a minus sign turning the pythagorean theorem for space time into either $a^2-b^2=c^2$, or $-a^2+b^2=c^2$.  Also the trigonometric functions in euclidean geometry get replaced with hyperbolic trigonometric functions in the geometry between space and time.

Would this mean that the modified functions in n spatial dimensions and 1 time dimension would get replaced with the bessel functions in $0$ space like dimensions and multiple time like dimensions, and if so would this be the correct equation for electric potential in $0$ space like dimensions, and $t$ time like dimensions in the case of massive photons, using natural units?
$$\varphi(r) = \frac{ (m r)^{\frac{t-1}{2}-1} Y_{\frac{t-1}{2}-1} (mr)}{(2 \pi)^\frac{t-1}{2}}\frac{1}{ r^{t-1-2}}$$

with $t$ being the number of time like dimensions, and $Y_n\left(x\right)$ being the bessel function of the second kind.

If this wouldn't be the correct formula would it be correct that the sign of electric force would depend on distance in $0$ space like and $t$ time like dimensions in the case of massive photons?

Comment: I have no idea, but I'm just curious: how can you have any matter/energy at all, with zero space-like dimensions?

Comment: @Time4Tea Even with $0$ space like dimensions two or more time like dimensions would be enough for the world line of each particle to be in a different direction and location in time from the world lines of particles.  The speed that particle B would have relative to particle A would be the tangent of the instantaneous time angle between the world line of particle A and particle B at a point on particle As world line.  As the kinetic energy of a particle was to increase its total energy would decrease.